# How to return incomplete body errors in django?

Tags: json, django, rest

```
class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
def list(self, request):
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    return Response({
      "code": "success",
      "orders": orders,
    })

def create(self, request):
    comment = request.data["comment"]
    product_id = request.data["product_id"]
    order = Order(comment=comment, product_id=product_id)
    order.save()
    return Response({
      "code": "success",
    })
```

I would like to return error if product_id is not supplied by the user in request body:

```
"code": "invalid-request",
"details": {
  "product_id": {
    "type": "required",
    "message": "Product id is required",
   }
 }
```

Also, there's KeyError if comment isn't supplied, but I don't want to make comment mandatory in request body. How do I set it to '' if its not supplied & still return success?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) to implement both input data validation and saving model. Note that below example use generic `serializers.Serializer`, but you probably want to use [serializers.ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#using-modelserializers) to validate `Order` data, since it will also handle creating model.

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    product_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    comment = serializers.CharField(required=False, default='')

class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        orders = Order.objects.all()
        return Response({
          "code": "success",
          "orders": orders,
        })

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            order = Order(**serializer.validated_data)
            order.save()
            return Response({
                "code": "success",
            })
        return Response({
            "code": "invalid-request",
            "details": {
                error: {
                    "type": serializer.errors[error][0].code,
                    "message": serializer.errors[error][0]
                } for error in serializer.errors}
        }, status=400)
```